# Mac Application installation testing process

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

Hello I am new to mac development and having some problem with my installation testing process 
When i archive my application and open with it installer it says that installation has been successful but the application actually does not show up.I have also deleted the built directory in order to avoid the multiple installation but it still does not work.Someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If an application with the same bundle identifier as the one you are installing already exists in the system, then the installer will overwrite the application at that location and **will not** install it to /Applications. So make sure that any duplicate copies of your app have been deleted from the system before you test the installer.

Comment: Yes that was the actual problem.The archived application was present there and the installer was updating the archived application.The problem was solved  when I deleted my archived application.